# Why does a Python script only use 6 out of 12 cores?

Tags: cpu, python, parallel-processing, multi-threaded, multitasking

I run [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper/) on an Intel-Mac with an Intel Core i7-CPU (Whisper doesn't seem to support AMD Radeon GPUs at the moment, hence I use CPU). When I run Whisper on this computer when it otherwise mostly is idle Whisper takes around 500-550 % CPU (1200 % is max - 6+6 cores), so around half of my CPU capacity is used. If I launch another Whisper it too takes 500-550 %, which means that my CPU is more or less fully used.

In other words, two files are processed at around half speed. I would prefer to process one file at full speed, that is, that the first Whisper process used maybe 1100 %.

Why does Python (?) only use half of the available CPU-capacity in a situation like this? Can this be controlled via some setting, flag or similar?

Comment: sounds like it doesn't like hyperthreads.

Comment: @FrankThomas It seems it doesn't like to **mix** regular threads and hyperthreads, doesn't it?

Comment: Have you looked at the per-core cpu usage to confirm whisper is only touching 6 cores? It's configured to use all available cores, so it may just be getting slowed down elsewhere like poor parallelization (cores waiting for other cores). You could try some kind of batching like jax https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/1277, but it will be less accurate for longer files

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Yes, when I look at my GUI CPU-monitor it is clear that Whisper just uses half of the cores if I just run one process, while if I run two processes all cores are fully used (more or less).

Comment: what is your max and average core temp while you are running a single instance? what scale is your CPU running at (as a percentage of max frequency)? note that 100% usage with 50% frequency still shows in the OS as 100%.

Comment: @FrankThomas Hmm, interesting. I don't know. Any suggestions for how to check this on an Intel-Mac?

Comment: sorry, I literally wasn't sure they still called it Finder. I think last time i used MacOS, it was the initial version of OSX. I'm just not a Apple person (and with a degree of prejudice). mabey  seems like the `powermetrics` command may be helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328965/is-there-a-way-to-see-current-cpu-frequency-in-macos-from-terminal-not-intel-po and https://www.lifewire.com/check-macbook-temperature-5184146

Answer (score 0):

`whisper` has a parameter for the number of threads.

```
--threads THREADS number of threads used by torch for CPU inference;
supercedes MKL_NUM_THREADS/OMP_NUM_THREADS (default: 0)
```

So to get full utilization on a CPU with 12 cores run

```
whisper --threads 12
```

Comment: Isn't Torch some Python library that only runs on supported GPUs?

Comment: Yes, [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) is a Python library but it has CPU support. If my answer to the original question resolved your issue please upvote, thanks!